# I reverted to some past commit , and made some changes how get back to my main commit?

Tags: git

I wanted to go several commits back by doing `git checkout 5fdf56f` then when I was exploring the past, somehow my IDE made some changes.

I don't want them just want to return to my recent commit.

git bash gives me the following error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:

I did:

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

but it didn't help.

how to go back?

Answer (score 1):

You should first reset all your current, uncommitted changes:

```
$ git reset HEAD --hard
```

And then you can just checkout back to the branch you were working on:

```
$ git checkout master # or any other branch...
```

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution:

```
git reset --hard <my recent commit>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!